# xspdf is polluting Google search results using Stack Overflow content

Tags: discussion, support, search, google

More and more lately I am getting a lot of Google results from xspdf when searching for programming questions.

e.g. https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/57076008.html

The problem is these are copy pasted Stack Overflow questions and answers, unformatted, apparently randomly fragmented and jumbled together. I don't know what kind of SEO they are using to get so high on the search results but the results are worse than useless.

Is there anything Stack Exchange can do about this? I realise the answer is probably no as they aren't breaching any licensing rules, but this is driving me crazy.